# Amazon GameCircle on Generic Android Device?

Tags: android, sdk, amazon-gamecircle

I've read Jeff's documentation inside and out. I'm still not able to log into GameCircle on my Samsung S3.

```
(31429): Unable to initialise AmazonGamesClient - service not ready. Status=CANNOT_INITIALIZE
```

I have the right security profile, app signature, api_key.txt. Is there anything I'm missing? Is there a GameCircle app I need to download or something? How would GameCircle even know I have an Amazon account?

I did download the Amazon Underground App Store app but that hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to the company that makes my engine (GameMaker Studio) it seems like they have bugs with the Amazon compile target.  So not my end afterall.

Answer (score -1):

QUOTE "When testing your GameCircle integration, if CANNOT_INITIALIZE AmazonGamesStatus is returned to your callback function by initialize(), you may not have correctly registered the package name and signature of the game build. Review the steps in [Setting Up Your GameCircle Configuration](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/gamecircle/docs/create-a-gamecircle-configuration), and then try again."

https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/gamecircle/docs/initialize-android